# Match doesn't change lRow when cycling trough Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

Using the match function below and looping trough worksheets the calculation is wrong when matching the worksheet after the sheet where a value was matched. So for example in 2nd sheet `lRow = 209` and in 3rd sheet where there should be no match the `lRow`is still 209 and not error/zero.

```
Sub lvl()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim starting_ws As Worksheet

    Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

         ws.Activate
         On Error Resume Next

         lRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("LVL", ws.Range("A1:A1000"), 0)


            If lRow > 0 Then
                If Cells(lRow, 2).Value > 1 Then

                    Cells(lRow, 2).Select
                    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                    TheActiveRow1 = ActiveCell.Row
                    TheActiveColumn1 = ActiveCell.Column

                    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                    TheActiveRow2 = ActiveCell.Row
                    TheActiveColumn2 = ActiveCell.Column

                End If
            End If

        Next

    starting_ws.Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
On Error Resume Next
lRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("LVL", ws.Range("A1:A1000"), 0)
```

`lRow` won't actually change if `"LVL"` isn't found, as if the Match fails, execution throws an error on that line (which you resume next from). If you want `lRow` to be zero when nothing is found, set it to zero before using the Match function:

```
On Error Resume Next
lRow = 0
lRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("LVL", ws.Range("A1:A1000"), 0)
```

Alternatively, consider using the `Application.Match` instead and catching it with `IsError`:

```
'On Error Resume Next <-no need for this
lRow = Application.Match("LVL", ws.Range("A1:A1000"), 0)
If IsError(lRow) then lRow = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

other than what CLR already pointed out there's another major flaw in your code: you don't reference current `ws` inside your loop

besides, all that `Select` and `Activate` isn't necessary, if not Dangerous

so you may want to try the following revision of your code

```
Sub lvl()

    Dim lRow As Long, TheActiveRow1 As Long, TheActiveColumn1 As Long, TheActiveRow2 As Long, TheActiveColumn2 As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        Dim found As Range
        If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then 'avoid processing active sheet
            With ws ' reference current worksheet
                Set found = .Range("A1:A1000").Find(what:="LVL", LookIn:=xlValue, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not found Is Nothing Then

                    With .Cells(found.Row, 2) 'reference referenced sheet column B cell in same row as found one
                        If .Value > 1 Then                    
                            With .End(xlDown).Select 'reference referenced cell next cell reached by .End(xlDown)
                                TheActiveRow1 = .Row
                                TheActiveColumn1 = .Column

                                With .End(xlDown)  'reference referenced cell next cell reached by .End(xlDown)                               
                                    TheActiveRow2 = .Row
                                    TheActiveColumn2 = .Column
                                End With
                            End With
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this I will do the revision!